# set.lower_bound function with pairs

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set, std-pair, lower-bound

I learned that set.lower_bound(key) function returns the value from the set as close as possible to the key, i was wondering how it works when the key passed is a pair(say x,y coordinates of a point), i.e the set contains pairs.

i encountered this in the following code snippet

```
 int compare(pairll a, pairll b)
{ 
        return a.px<b.px; 
}
double closest_pair(pairll pnts[],int n)
{
        sort(pnts,pnts+n,compare);
        double best=INF;
        set<pairll> box;
        box.insert(pnts[0]);
        int left = 0;
        for (int i=1;i<n;++i)
        {
            while (left<i && pnts[i].px-pnts[left].px > best)
                box.erase(pnts[left++]);
            for(typeof(box.begin()) it=box.lower_bound(make_pair(pnts[i].py-best, pnts[i].px-best));it!=box.end() && pnts[i].py+best>=it->py;it++)
                best = min(best, sqrt(pow(pnts[i].py - it->py, 2.0)+pow(pnts[i].px - it->px, 2.0)));
            box.insert(pnts[i]);
        }
        return best;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I learned that set.lower_bound(key) function returns the value from the set as close as possible to the key

First of all, that is false. It is always the best idea to refer to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) for correct information. Here's what has to say about std::set::lower_bound:

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) key.

Hence it's not the element *as close as possible* but rather the first element greater or equal.

> i was wondering how it works when the key passed is a pair(say x,y coordinates of a point), i.e the set contains pairs.

As it would work for any other type `T`. It internally is implemented as a bst(commonly as a red-black tree). Hence the lookup is `O(nlogn)`. What's the order/comparator used you say? std::set is basically:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

As you can see, it accepts a comparator as a template parameter with default set to [std::less](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less). Hence it

> checks whether the first argument is less than the second

You ask how it compares two pairs? Here's what doc on [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) has to say:

> Compares lhs and rhs lexicographically by operator<, that is, compares the first elements and only if they are equivalent, compares the second elements.

So now you get how std::lower_bound works. Its a traversal over the underlying bst to find the first element equal to or greater than the key, given the tree ordered according to the comparator.

I hope things are crystal clear now :)

Comment: thanks for clearing it out @theWiseBro , it was really helpful.